# functionality to compare the database

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function which can do some test over the database. its something i am creating new to my code.

for example i have a database of survey in which we are getting response so first question(DD1) is like do you have a mobile and 1 = Yes , 2 = no, then question(DD2) is do you have android phone then answer should be yes or no.

case 1 : if dd1 have 1 then there should be answer in dd2 if this fulfill then column (TT2) in new data frame be like "should be ok"

case 2 : if dd1 have 2 then there should not be any response in dd2 if this is true the tt2 is blank but if it is false then tt2 be "cant be ok check the data" .

case 3 : if dd1 and dd2 have no response then tt2 be " can be ok "

```
df <- data.frame(`id` = c("se201",  "se202",    "se203",    "se204",    "se205",    "se206",    "se207",    "se208",    "se209"),
                 `DD1` = c(2,   1,  2,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  1),
                 `DD2` = c(NA,  "Yes",NA,   "Yes",  "Yes",  NA, "No",   NA, "Yes"),
                 `DD3` = c("Old",   "New",  "Old",  "New",  "Old",  "Old",  "New",  "New",  "Old"))


# mutate(df,
#        new_col = if_else(condition = have.mobile == "Yes" & !is.na(Which.model),
#                          true = "should be ok",
#                          false = NULL
#        )
```

the out is required like

[image]

Comment: Your input has names `DD1` through `DD3`, your output has names `TT1` and the others are dropped. Additionally, assuming that your `TT1` and `DD1` columns should be the same, then why the empty value in the third row?

Comment: because the output required is another dataframe , i do not  want to mutate it.
the empty value is just response from the respondent . this is just a scenario can be happened

Comment: TT2 and DD2 are different columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `dplyr::case_when` attempt:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    TT2 = case_when(
      DD1 == 1 & !is.na(DD2) ~ "should be ok",
      DD1 == 2 & is.na(DD2) ~ "",
      DD1 == 2 & !is.na(DD2) ~ "cant be ok check the data",
      is.na(DD1) & is.na(DD2) ~ "can be ok"
    )
  )
#      id DD1  DD2 DD3                       TT2
# 1 se201   2 <NA> Old                          
# 2 se202   1  Yes New              should be ok
# 3 se203   2 <NA> Old                          
# 4 se204   1  Yes New              should be ok
# 5 se205   1  Yes Old              should be ok
# 6 se206   1 <NA> Old                      <NA>
# 7 se207   2   No New cant be ok check the data
# 8 se208   2 <NA> New                          
# 9 se209   1  Yes Old              should be ok
```

Your logic is missing at least one condition (seen in row 6) unless I misinterpreted your three bullets. Regardless, I think your way-forward can use this as a good start.